# Overriding a file in Linux using python

Tags: python, linux

I need to be able to override an existing file named `a.zip`
with the content of another file called `tmp.zip` and doing this without removing the file `a.zip` first, `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()` don't seem to be suitable as both require that the dest file won't be exist before launching them.

Any ideas how do I do copy that override existing file - it may be doing a remove in inner implementation but it must be atomic operation.